# Linux: sum of maximums of each row

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Salam,
I need a shell script that would take data like below in txt file

```
8.0    5.2   6.6   4.0   1.6
7.1    8.0   2.3   7.2   2.8
4.0    3.0   2.0   5.0   2.1
```

and gives as output the sum of maximums, it means sum of maximums of each row , which is for the matrixe above max first line 8, max second line 8, and max last line 5, i want to have as result 21 which is (8+8+5), thank you very much

Comment: Note that it was *irony*. In [so] some effort is expected and people will help if see that you tried something. If you just ask for something it looks like you do not have idea how to do it and just want the result.

Comment: While many appreciate irony, new users may be more receptive to kinder advice.

Comment: @fatima, here's some practical advice: read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @superdesk believe me I am normally quite helpful, just that I found it very "mandatory" coming from a person who has already posted some questions before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'd prefer seeing some effort described in the question, but I need the `awk` practice anyway.

You could do it using a simple loop;

```
awk '{max=$1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i>max)max=$i;sum=sum+max;}END{print sum+0}'
```

It basically just loops through all columns per line to get the max, and sums it up in `sum`.

The `END` section runs when the file has been completely processed and just prints the sum.

Comment: You need to reset the `max` value. I came out with something quite similar: `awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) max=max<$i?$i:max; res+=max; max=0} END{print res}' file`

Comment: effectively, i have two codes but which dont work: the first is        awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) max[NR]=max[NR]>$i?max[NR]:$i}END{for (i in max) sum+=max[i];print sum}' file

Comment: and the second :          
#!/bin/bash

let 'sum=0'
while read ligne
do
    let 'max=0'
    if [[ "$1" > "$max" ]]; then 
     let 'max=$1'
    else 
     if [[ "$2" > "$max" ]]; then
         let 'max=$2'
     else
         if [[ "$3" > "$max" ]]; then
             let 'max=$3'
         else
             if [[ "$4" > "$max" ]]; then
                 let 'max=$4'
             fi
         fi
      fi            
    fi 
    let 'sum = sum + $max'
done < matrice.txt

echo "La somme est " $sum

Comment: `i<NF` needs to be `i<=NF`. You could also use `sum+=max` instead of `sum=sum+max`. The END section should be `print sum+0` or `printf "%d",sum` to print a number even for empty files. +1 for a reasonable approach though.

Comment: it doesn't work as previous codes, i think i have a problem but i dont know what is it

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the feedback, turned out I _really_ needed the practice :) Updated with your suggestions.